# javascript sort not working correctly with string

Tags: javascript, sorting

I used JavaScript code to sort  a string from page elements input, and it's something like this:

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
input=a[0].innerHTML;
input=input.split(',');
input=input.sort();
alert(input);
var str=input.join();
str=str.replace(" ","");
```

the input string has comma and white spaces ,so if the input is something like:

```
yet, must, has, wants, would, some, are, let, own, can, could, which, his, had, got, our, only, also, every, after, other, may, you, them, while, ever, what, get, its, why, their, her, him, just, say, this, than, have, able, least, like, whom, nor, cannot, into, among
```

the output is :

```
able, after, also, among, are, can, cannot, could, ever, every, get, got, had, has, have, her, him, his, into, its, just, least, let, like, may, must, nor, only, other, our, own, say, some, than, their, them, this, wants, what, which, while, whom, why, would, you,yet
```

and you can notice that yet should be before you,so whats wrong????

Comment: just wonderful , why the vote down????????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove white spaces before sorting:

```js
var input = 'yet, must, has, wants, would, some, are, let, own, can, could, which, his, had, got, our, only, also, every, after, other, may, you, them, while, ever, what, get, its, why, their, her, him, just, say, this, than, have, able, least, like, whom, nor, cannot, into, among';
input = input.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',').sort();
console.log(input);
```

Comment: It is a regex that replaces white spaces in string, you can find it on google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split with space.

```
input = input.split(', ');
```

Otherwise you have a space at the beginning of the string.

```js
var input = 'yet, must, has, wants, would, some, are, let, own, can, could, which, his, had, got, our, only, also, every, after, other, may, you, them, while, ever, what, get, its, why, their, her, him, just, say, this, than, have, able, least, like, whom, nor, cannot, into, among';
console.log(input.split(', ').sort());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```